# MVC working with CSHTML href

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this cshtml partial layout view in my system

```
<div class="row" style="background: #816BFA; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-top: 30px; height: 7%">
    <h class="col-sm-4" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; color: black; height: 40px; top: 8px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>@Html.ActionLink("Truck List","TruckList")// this</h>
    <a href="index.html" class="col-sm-4" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; color: black; height: 40px; top: 8px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i> Reports</a>
    <a href="index.html" class="col-sm-4" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; color: black; height: 40px; top: 8px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> User Accounts</a>
</div>
```

The output is this

[image]

You might not see the text `"Truck List"` Because in html.action link if you click, it always turns blue. Is there a solution to turn it black like the other text in the menu? And this link redirects to Action "Trucklist" Controller "Trucks"

Comment: Just use css to style your `<a>` elements - `a:hover { color: ???; }` and `a:visited { color: ???; }` etc (and use css to replace those horrible inline styles you currently have)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your below code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Truck List","TruckList")
```

With this:

```
Html.ActionLink(
"Truck List",
"Create",
CONTROLLERNAME,
null,
new { @style= "color: black;" }
)
```

Comment: i did this but when im on http://host/Trucks/AddTruckJobOrder when i click the link, it redirects to /Trucks/AddTruckJobOrder/trucklist how will it redirect to trucks/trucklist only

Comment: @JohnPaulCirilos - try specifying controller name as well in your ActionLink.

Answer (score 0):

**Just add this CSS class:**

```
h a {
        color: black;
    }
```